# Comparing Values in Dictionary to Elements in Nested List

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and a list. I am trying to compare list1[0] with values of 'halal' in canteen1. After, I would like to print the answer out in a statement

Scenario 1:

```
canteen1 = {'price':[ ],'halal':['western','noodles']}

list1 = [['korean','japanese','western'],[ ],[ ]]
```

output: You could try the halal western at canteen1!

Scenario 2:

```
canteen1 = {'price':[ ],'halal':['western','noodles']}

list1 = [['korean','japanese','western','noodles'],[ ],[ ]]
```

output: You could try the halal western, noodles at canteen1!

P.S. spent ages searching for an answer here but could not find it. I am really new to programming so apologies for this amateur question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
canteen1 = {'price':[ ],'halal':['western','noodles']}

list1 = [['korean','japanese','western', 'noodles'],[ ],[ ]]

halal = canteen1['halal']

result = list(set(halal) & set(list1[0]))

if result:
        print("You could try the halal", ', '.join(result) ,"at canteen1!")    
else :
        print("You could not try the halal at canteen1!")
```

In the else(false) statement, it cannot show the same result as the if(true) statement because there is no same element so you can just say "You could not try the halal at canteen1!" Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot but I would like to check not just for boolean True/False but the actual elements and then print them out (like how in Scenario 1 vs Scenario 2). Thanks again appreciate it!!

Comment: @BenedictLow don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you :) happy coding!

Comment: Yeap it works! Accepted the answer thank you so much!